# What is the comma character meaning in right side of expression in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Excuse me for this basic question but, I couldn't find the answer on Google.
I am new to Ruby and came across to this line of code:

```
self.primary_keys = :role_id, :action_name
```

What I understand from it is that `self.primary_keys` is a Class variable and is assigned an array or hash of symbols?
What means the right side of the expression (`:role_id, :action_name`)?
What is the type of it?

Comment: This looks like a parallel assignment of the hash keys.

Comment: See the doc for [multiple assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment). It's well-written and covers a number of situations. In fact, that entire file deserves carefully study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's two symbols separated by a comma, and is an implicit array.

Equivalent to

```
self.primary_keys = [:role_id, :action_name]
```

It's more common to see the technique used on the left side of an assignment.

```
name, age = ["George", 21]

puts name
=> "George"

puts age
=> 21
```

The feature lets you swap the contents of variables without an intermediate variable.

For example, in some languages to swap `a` and `b` you need a temporary variable

```
temporary = a
a = b
b = temporary
```

In Ruby you can do

```
a, b = b, a
```

Answer (score 0):

It's assignment

x, y = ["Srini", 25]

puts x
=> "Srini"

puts y
=> 25

Comment: A quibble: `puts y` displays the string `y.to_s`, which is why you should just write, `x #=> "Srini"; y #=> 25`.